# List of Tables - Table name configuration inside ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

When I use \listoftables, it shows me:

```
TABELA 1 title . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 8
```

I'm trying to make it shows:

```
TABELA 1 - title . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 8
```

How could I change it using tocloft package?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc), hope you're open to it (I know you mentioned [`tocloft`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft) )

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titlecontents{table}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{\addvspace{.5cm}}%                                 % above code (e.g vertical space)
{\contentsmargin{0pt} \bfseries                     % numbered entry format
    TABLE~\thecontentslabel\enspace - \enspace%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[\addvspace{.5pc}]                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)


\begin{document}

\listoftables
\chapter{Test one}
\section{Test one one}

\loop
\begin{table}
    \caption{Test table two}
\end{table}
\ifnum\value{table}<5\repeat


\chapter{Test two}
\section{Test two two}

\loop
\begin{table}
    \caption{Test table two}
\end{table}
\ifnum\value{table}<5\repeat

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{1em}% extra space
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen} % add the extra space

\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cfttabdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ - }
```

[image]